# how to show sub category data by category in flutter from sqlite db

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite

```css
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stone_recipe_app/homepage.dart';
import 'package:stone_recipe_app/models/recipe.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';

class DetailedScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  DetailedScreen({Key? key, required this.recipe, required this.index}) : super(key: key);
  List<Recipe>? recipe;
  int index;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Row(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
              },
            ),
            Text(
              'Back',
              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff007AFF)),
            )
          ],
        ),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Color(0xff007AFF)),
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            recipe![index].recipe_name,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200),
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: 400,
                height: 200,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(9.0)),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("images/cook.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
              const Icon(
                Icons.file_download_sharp,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 40,
              ),
              const Icon(
                Icons.document_scanner,
                size: 40,
              ),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Share.share(recipe![index].recipe_prep);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.share,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 40,
                  )),
              const Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 40,
              ),
            ]),
            SizedBox(
              height: 500,
              child: Card(
                elevation: 4,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Ingredients',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(recipe![index].recipe_ingrdients),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Method',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      recipe![index].recipe_prep,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

    // Scaffold(
    //   appBar: AppBar(
    //     title: Text(recipe![index].recipe_name),
    //   ),
    //   body: Center(
    //     child: SingleChildScrollView(
    //       child: Column(
    //         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    //         children: [
    //           SelectableText(recipe![index].recipe_cat),
    //           Text(recipe![index].recipe_prep),
    //           Text(recipe![index].recipe_id.toString()),
    //           Text(recipe![index].recipe_ingrdients),
    //           Text(recipe![index].image_name),
    //           OutlinedButton(
    //               onPressed: () {
    //                 Share.share(recipe![index].recipe_prep);
    //               },
    //               child: Text('Share'))
    //         ],
    //       ),
    //     ),
    //   ),
    // );
  }
}
```

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stone_recipe_app/detailedScreen.dart';
import 'package:stone_recipe_app/models/recipe.dart';
import 'package:stone_recipe_app/services/db_services.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final dbservice = DataBaseService();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    dbservice.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Recipe App')),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Recipe>>(
            future: dbservice.getRecipe(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => DetailedScreen(
                                    recipe: snapshot.data,
                                    index: index,
                                  )));
                    },
                    title: Text(snapshot.data![index].recipe_name, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    // trailing: Text(
                    //   snapshot.data![index].recipe_cat,
                    //   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    //   overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                    // ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUj7D.jpg)i am trying to show data from sqlite db in flutter when user click on country category like india china after  user click user navigate to other page which are recipe name related to chine or related to india i am trying to show data from sqlite db in flutter when user click on country category like india china after  user click user navigate to other page which are recipe name related to chine or related to india  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3LOQ.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Whenever you ask a questions please put code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

add `group_list_view: ^1.1.1` package in your pubspec.yaml file.
try below the example then implement it in your project

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:group_list_view/group_list_view.dart';
import 'package:group_listview_example/app_colors.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

Map<String, List> _elements = {
  'Team A': ['Klay Lewis', 'Ehsan Woodard', 'River Bains'],
  'Team B': ['Toyah Downs', 'Tyla Kane'],
  'Team C': ['Marcus Romero', 'Farrah Parkes', 'Fay Lawson', 'Asif Mckay'],
  'Team D': [
    'Casey Zuniga',
    'Ayisha Burn',
    'Josie Hayden',
    'Kenan Walls',
    'Mario Powers'
  ],
  'Team Q': ['Toyah Downs', 'Tyla Kane', 'Toyah Downs'],
};

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Group List View Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Group List View Demo'),
        ),
        body: GroupListView(
          sectionsCount: _elements.keys.toList().length,
          countOfItemInSection: (int section) {
            return _elements.values.toList()[section].length;
          },
          itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
          groupHeaderBuilder: (BuildContext context, int section) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 8),
              child: Text(
                _elements.keys.toList()[section],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10),
          sectionSeparatorBuilder: (context, section) => SizedBox(height: 10),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, IndexPath index) {
    String user = _elements.values.toList()[index.section][index.index];
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 8,
        child: ListTile(
          contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 10.0),
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            child: Text(
              _getInitials(user),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
            ),
            backgroundColor: _getAvatarColor(user),
          ),
          title: Text(
            _elements.values.toList()[index.section][index.index],
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          ),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String _getInitials(String user) {
    var buffer = StringBuffer();
    var split = user.split(" ");
    for (var s in split) buffer.write(s[0]);

    return buffer.toString().substring(0, split.length);
  }

  Color _getAvatarColor(String user) {
    return AppColors
        .avatarColors[user.hashCode % AppColors.avatarColors.length];
  }
}
```